# Quartz Clustering in Enterprise Applications

Tags: quartz-scheduler, horizontal-scaling, cluster-mode

We have a microservice running in production using quartz scheduler (jdbcjobstore)  version 2.5.0-rc1 . Till now we were running only a single node of the service and everything worked fine for us.

Now we plan to horizontally scale this service and the only issue we see is with Quartz Scheduling.

As a trial we tried running quartz in a cluster mode in a non production environment
and don't see any issues in the initial run.

Has anyone faced challenges with quartz clustering or any down side to it ?